# How to consume .Net webservice in angular post method?

Tags: asp.net, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

how to call post method in angular 5 and ionic 3.

**My angular code is:**

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body= {
      records:
               this.records
             };
    this.http.post('http://localhost:13799/HealthPotliWebService.asmx/getsingleproductdetails', 
    "{body2:" + JSON.stringify(body) + "}",options)
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .subscribe(data=>{
       console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

**this is my webservice class**

my class is like this :

```
    public class body2
    {
        public List<records> records { get; set; }
    }
    public class records
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**webservice code :**

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getsingleproductdetails(body2 body2)
    {
          // some code here
          return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(resources);
    }
```

**Return type of my webservice is:**

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    {"error_msg":"Success","status":"0","medicinename":"CROCIN","description":"\u003cdiv style=\u0027text-align:justify;\u0027\u003e\u003cu\u003e\u003cb\u003eParacetamol\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/u\u003e-\u003cu\u003e125mg\u003c/u\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e\u003c/div\u003e","lstComments":[],"rateValue":0,"potliMoney":0,"offer":null}
    </string>
```

Comment: There is no angular 3.. do you mean angular 5/ionic 3? Also which http module are you using?

Comment: sorry yes it  is angular5 and ionic 3  ..... import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';    i am using this module

Comment: Not sure why you are doing:`"{body2:" + JSON.stringify(body) + "}"`

Comment: Use httpClient, not http

Comment: public class body3
    {
        public List<UnSoldProduct> records { get; set; }
    }
    public class body2
    {
        public List<records> records { get; set; }
    }
    public class records
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }